# Problem with mathastext package

Tags: math-mode, luatex

The following very simple code does not work here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Droid Sans}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
   \section{test}
       test $\frac{1}{2}$
\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be with the `mathastext` package, when I load it I get the following error:

> ```
> LaTeX Error: Command `\mathdollar' already defined.
> ```

It happens with any font, it's not related to the use of Droid Sans.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to consult the documentation of `mathastext`:

> When using `mathastext` with either XeTeX or LuaLaTeX it is
>   recommended to use the `fontspec` package. Else, some of the encoding
>   dependent things done by mathastext like using the en-dash character
>   to get a minus sign in math mode will not work correctly. **Furthermore,
>   it is necessary to load `fontspec` with its `no-math` option, and this
>   must happen before loading `mathastext`.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Droid Sans}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
   \section{test}
       test $\frac{1}{2}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: you're right, I will contact the author of the package, thanks

Comment: @JackO in the code you can un-comment the `\setmainfont{Droid Sans}` line in order to check that "mathastextification" now works (it does on my system).